# How can I pass two values to a Java servlet?

Tags: java, jsf

I am developing a JSF application which has a servlet to display binary images. I have it working with one parameter but wanted to pass two parameters. It only seems to get the first parameter. My mapping looks like this.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.system.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I call the servlet it looks like this

```
<p:graphicImage value="image?app=avatar?id=#{bean.imgId}" />
```

In my servlet I get the parameters like so

```
 String id = request.getParameter("id");
 String app = request.getParameter("app");
```

If I output the app string it displays this

```
 avatar?id=166
```

How can I allow the servlet url-patter to take in two values and be able to parse them using the getParameter method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for encoding URL parameters is to separate key-value pairs with an ampersand (`&`):

```
<p:graphicImage value="image?app=avatar&id=#{bean.imgId}" />
```

Comment: That looks like an extract from an XML file: &amp;

Comment: could be, or could just be a JSP taglib

Answer (score 1):

The JSP tag should be written as:

```
<p:graphicImage value="image?app=avatar&amp;id=#{bean.imgId}" />
```

Parameters in the query part of a URL should be separated by '&'s not '?'s.

(You can ignore this, but them you won't be able to use `ServletRequest.getParameter(String)` to retrieve the parameter values.  Instead you'll have to use `ServletRequest.getQueryString()` and parse the individual parameters yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

Use ampersand before all parameters but the first one:

```
<p:graphicImage value="image?app=avatar&id=#{bean.imgId}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:graphicImage value="image?app=avatar&id=#{bean.imgId}" />
```

& instead of the second ?